# W/dalvikvm: Link of class '*;' failed with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got this weird issue. I have two activities in my app. I added support jar in libs folder and then added it to build path.

Now the weird part, one activity runs normally with no error but when I tried to call other activity I get **W/dalvikvm: Link of class '*;' failed with ClassNotFoundException** error.

My logcat trace is:

```
04-09 12:15:04.171: W/dalvikvm(5027): Link of class 'Lcom/hht/cameraappr/MainActivity;' failed

04-09 12:15:04.179: D/AndroidRuntime(5027): Shutting down VM
04-09 12:15:04.179: W/dalvikvm(5027): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hht.cameraappr/com.hht.cameraappr.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hht.cameraappr.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hht.cameraappr-2.apk]
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hht.cameraappr.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hht.cameraappr-2.apk]
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
04-09 12:15:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(5027):     ... 11 more
```

I have registered my activity in manifest file.
I tried all Link of class failed and ClassNotFoundException answer from stackoverflow but didnt solve my issue.

Further I also want to know main cause of this error and why my class is not getting package in apk?

Comment: Can you try cleaning and building your project? Go to project > clean and then  build.

Comment: I have tried all that.

Answer (score 0):

Put your .so libraries inside libs folder not only .jar files.

Comment: I have included all the needed jar and so files from very beginning of project. Issue is something else, its not packaging my MainActivity class for some reason.

Comment: Check your Manifiest file , try writing entery package name. Probably you change the location of the MainActivity class.